# Whose story doesn't add up?

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

> "It's been weeks. This is taking too long. We finally rounded up the
> four suspects, the four people seen ducking into nearby shops right
> around the time of death, got their statements and still don't know
> who the killer is. You were the first officer on the scene, right? You
> said you were nearby and saw someone with short hair and green clothes
> going in to the deli?"
>
> "Right. And from other witnesses, we have that among the four, each
> went in to a different store: the deli, the pharmacy, the clothing
> store and the grocer's. Each had a different color of clothing: red,
> green, blue and yellow. Each was carrying something different:
> nothing, a shopping bag, a backpack and a briefcase. And each had a
> different hairstyle. The four hairstyles were different enough to be
> easily distinguished: short, long, bald and a mohawk."
>
> "All we really have to go on are their hazy memories though.
>
> Arden said, 'I was coming back from getting my mohawk done, but I
> don't remember where I went, not the grocer's though. ... I saw a
> couple other people walking around. One heading for the pharmacy had
> long hair. The other was wearing green.'
>
> Blair said, 'I went to the grocer's that day. The only other thing I
> remember is seeing someone with yellow clothes carrying a shopping
> bag.'
>
> Channing said, 'I remember going to the clothing store. ... I don't
> think I was carrying anything at the time. The only other person I saw
> was carrying a briefcase into the pharmacy.'
>
> Devon said 'I wasn't wearing red that day. ... I saw someone with
> empty hands. They weren't wearing red either. ... There was also
> someone with a backpack and short hair.'"
>
> "That's not much to go on, but it has to be one of them. They were the
> only ones in the right place at the right time."
>
> "Yeah. Something about this doesn't add up though. Someone's lying and
> I have a feeling whoever it is is the killer."

Who was the killer?

*This is version 2. The first version had a significant error that meant there was no solution.*

Comment: Just in case the [tag:logic-grid] tag is actually relevant, [here you go](https://i.imgur.com/YAQgd62.png) :-)

Comment: I can't believe this. I checked this a dozen times, but somehow there's still two solutions. :P

Comment: In case you decide to rewrite, maybe change the hairstyles to some other property; a hairstyle is easy to verify during an interview.

Comment: It's been several weeks, so hairstyles might have changed, but yeah, good point.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I've uploaded a newer version with corrections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the killer is

> C (channing )

> [image: imgur is slow]

May be other solutions are also possible , I didn't checked them

Comment: If OP marks this as correct I won't submit my answer, since I came up with a very different conclusion and I'm worried I did it wrong.

Comment: This isn't the intended solution, but your logic is sound, so I'll accept this answer and post a V3.

Answer (score 3):

There's one other possibility from Aakash's answer, though it's a little lateral thinking:

> The first officer on scene is the culprit. If we ignore his statements about the person entering the deli, we can construct a consistent grid for the four people from all of their statements:

> A went to the deli, wore yellow, had a mohawk, and carried a bag. B went to the grocer, wore red, had short hair, and carried a backpack. C went to the clothing store, wore green, was bald, and carried nothing. D went to the pharmacy, wore blue, had long hair, and carried a briefcase

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion.  It was a bit suspicious to me that the first officer also is presented as a witness.

Comment: rto13(Guvf vf gur vagraqrq nafjre, gubhtu V nccneragyl zrffrq vg hc ntnva. V'yy cbfg n I3, fb vs lbh nafjre gung (vg fubhyq or irel fvzvyne), V'yy npprcg lbhe nafjre gurer.)

Answer (score 2):

> I found three possible solutions, all fit the statements (given that one person is lying): 
> 1. The cop is lying and therefore is the murderer:
> Arden MOHAWK DELI YELLOW SHOP_BAG 
> Blair SHORT GROCER RED BACKPACK 
> Channing BALD CLOTHING GREEN NOTHING 
> Devon LONG PHARMACY BLUE BRIEFCASE 
>  
> 2. Channing is lying and therefore is the murderer:
> Arden MOHAWK CLOTHING RED BRIEFCASE 
> Blair BALD GROCER BLUE NOTHING 
> Channing SHORT DELI GREEN BACKPACK 
> Devon LONG PHARMACY YELLOW SHOP_BAG 
>  
> 3. Channing is lying and therefore is the murderer (slightly different solution):
> Arden MOHAWK CLOTHING BLUE NOTHING 
> Blair BALD GROCER RED BRIEFCASE 
> Channing SHORT DELI GREEN BACKPACK 
> Devon LONG PHARMACY YELLOW SHOP_BAG